How to flip error with no-error with projectreactor in Java?
I have instance of Mono<MyClass1>
It can either have value or be an error. Now I need to convert it to Mono<MyClass2> where error and no-error flipped
mono
   .doMagic( $ -> {
      if( error ) {
         return Mono.just( new MyClass2 .. )
      }
      else if( no-error ) {
         return Mono.error(...)
      }

   }

Is this possible?

You can materialize/dematerialize the "low-level" signals of "onNext", "onError" and "onCompleted". Inside a map() call you can check if you have an "onNext" signal or an "onError" signal and generate a swapped "onError" signal or an "onNext" signal. The code can look like this:
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Mono<First> source = Mono.just(new First());
    //Mono<First> source = Mono.error(new RuntimeException());
    Mono<Second> sourceSecond = source.materialize().map(it -> {
        if (it.isOnError()) {
            return Signal.next(new Second());
        } else {
            return Signal.error(new RuntimeException());
        }
    }).dematerialize();
    sourceSecond.subscribe(
            it -> { System.out.println("Value received"); },
            e -> { System.out.println("Error received"); },
            () -> { System.out.println("Completed"); });
}

The first variant will give you an error:
Error received

The second variant (when you swapped the source variable) will get you a value:
Value received
Completed

